# How do I recover my lost windows partitions after installing ubuntu 16.04 lts?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, testdisk

I am trying to recover with testdisk, but I don't know the correct options to select in testdisk and I cant take risk of selecting wrong options. When I selected Quick search I can see two partitionsas shown below.

```
Linux                    0  32 33 60554 194 56  972810240
P Linux Swap           60554 227 26 60801  47 46    3956736

Structure: Ok.  Use Up/Down Arrow keys to select partition.
Use Left/Right Arrow keys to CHANGE partition characteristics:
=Primary bootable  P=Primary  L=Logical  E=Extended  D=Deleted
Keys A: add partition, L: load backup, T: change type, P: list files,
Enter: to continue
```

I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: Are you sure the partitions are lost/deleted, or you just can't able to see in Grub?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to make it possible to experiment without destroying the [original] drive: Clone it to another drive with *ddrescue*, and ***do the recovery work on the cloned copy***. If you make a mistake, you can clone from the original drive again.

See [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986), and links from it for more details. (It is written for pendrives, but can be applied to all kinds of mass storage devices, also hard disk drives, solid state drives and memory cards.)